# Why can I not access my member variable?

Tags: c++

I have the below code split between a header and source file. In the function insert it states AllBridges vector is not initialised (it doesnt even seem to recognise it?) and nextBridge is not assigned a value- except I thought i did in the constructor??

```
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Bridge
{
    public:
        Bridge(int);
        void insert(Bridge);

    private:

        int nextBridge;
        vector<Bridge> AllBridges;
};


#include "StdAfx.h"
#include "Bridge.h"

using namespace std;        

    Bridge::Bridge(int size){
        AllBridges.reserve(size);
        nextBridge= 0;      
    }

    void insert(Bridge AddBridge){
        AllBridges[nextBridge] = AddBridge;
    }
```

Comment: You should use member initializer syntax to initialize variables in the constructor, rather than explicit assign statements.

Answer (score 6):

Should be

```
void Bridge::insert(Bridge AddBridge)
```

instead of

```
void insert(Bridge AddBridge)
```

Comment: @JerryCoffin I just saw the error message and the cause. You explain the rest well enough in your answer. Besides, I's sure that once he compiles and runs the code, he'll see the problems himself. Can be a good learning experience.

Comment: Fair enough -- you do answer the question he asked, just not the question(s) he should have asked. :-)

Comment: @JerryCoffin I honestly didn't read the whole thing (the un-qualified name popped out). Maybe I should have. No point in editing now.

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to duplicate functionality that's already part of `vector`.

Instead of keeping track of nextBridge on your own, you should just let the `vector` do its job, and keep track of how many `bridge`s you've inserted. Instead of `insert`ing at a specified location, you just need to use `push_back` to add to the end of the `vector`, so your code becomes:

```
Bridge::Bridge(int size){
    AllBridges.reserve(size);
}

void Bridge::insert(Bridge AddBridge){
    AllBridges.push_back(AddBridge);
}
```

...and you can simply remove `nextBridge` from your definition of `Bridge` entirely.

As an aside, I think you're making a fundamental mistake though: you're conflating the notion of a single bridge with the notion of a collection of all bridges. This is a common mistake (sometimes made by people who definitely aren't beginners) but it leads almost inevitably to problems. Just for example, each `Bridge` you insert into your `AllBridges` has an `AllBridges` of its own (that'll probably be empty, but who knows).

You really want `Bridge` to *just* represent a single bridge, then (if necessary) have a separate type to represent a collection of bridges -- if it really adds something useful beyond `std::vector<Bridge>`.

Edit: I suppose I should add one other possibility: perhaps you really do want the `Bridge` type to keep track of all instances of itself that ever get instantiated. If so, you want to make your `AllBridges` a `static` member, so you have a single instance of it for the class instead of a separate instance of it for every object of the class.

Answer (score 2):

Calling `reserve` on a `std::vector` ensures that it has enough capacity to host such many elements if they were added. It does not resize the vector, it only changes its capacity. What you are looking for is `resize`.

You are also missing `Bridge::` in your `insert` member function definition.